# Helm3: How can i get a value from existing variable in values.yml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, helm3

I have a chart where its `values.yml` looks like :

```
containerPorts:
  http: 8080 ###### this is [1]
  https: 8443

networkPolicy:
  enabled: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
  ingressRules:
    customRules:
      - from:
          - namespaceSelector:
              matchLabels:
                kubernetes.io/metadata.name: kube-system
            podSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app: ingress-appgw
        ports:
          - protocol: TCP
            port: '{{ .Values.containerPorts.http }}' ###### this is [2]
```

I would like to reference [1] in [2]. And when i install a release, i get the following:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: NetworkPolicy.extensions "wp-wordpress-ingress" is invalid: spec.ingress[0].ports[0].port: Invalid value: "8
080": must contain at least one letter or number (a-z, 0-9)
```

FYI: this chart is wordpress.

Any help please ?

Comment: `'{{ .Values.containerPorts.http | int }}' `?

Comment: Hello @Adiii : Always the same error

Comment: in fact `helm template ... | grep 8080` gives this : `- port: '8080'`  (Notice the signle quote arround 8080) And when i put 8080 instead of jinja2 it works fine. I guess the problem is on single quote

Comment: Possible, give it try with double qoutes

Comment: i did it before : D, and always the same error

Comment: How do you the templating, which chart so i can dirty my hand

Comment: this one : `helm repo add azure-marketplace https://marketplace.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo`

Comment: and the cmd for templating is : `helm template wp azure-marketplace/wordpress -n app --create-namespace --set externalDatabase.user=$DB_USER --set externalDatabase.password=$DB_PASSWORD -f manifests/values-wp.yml | grep 8080`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247206/discussion-between-adiii-and-mohamed).

Comment: Does the `port:` option ultimately set an [Ingress port object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/ingress-v1/#IngressBackend)?  That can reference a port by name in its matching Service, so you could likely just specify `port: http` here and let Kubernetes do the wiring itself.

Answer (score 0):

Helm `values.yaml` is a plain yaml file, please see reference for the default `values.yaml` use from Helm's official documentation here: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/.

You can either use a `--set` and pass individual parameter overrides like:

```
helm install <release-name> <your-chart> --set networkPolicy.ingressRules.customRules[0].ports[0].port=8080
```

Or you can create your `own-values.yaml` that will override when called like:

```
helm install <release-name> <your-chart> --values <own-values.yaml file path>
```

The contents of `own-values.yaml` can be:

```
networkPolicy:
  ingressRules:
    customRules:
        ports:
          - protocol: TCP
            port: 8080
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my qustion is how to set the port number dynamically (not in hard coded manner as you said ^^). And Adiii (see comments before) was tried my configuration and it works fine for him. I will test againt in diffirent terminal and/or k8s cluster and keep you informed : )

Comment: @Mohamed supplying overrides to values.yaml is not hard-coding. As far as I know the values.yaml is a plain yaml file and go templates are added inside the files used in templates directory of a helm chart. 

The solution you seek can be done outside of helm chart using other scripts that can replace helm values.yaml before packaging and publishing your chart.

Also it will help if you provide the actual or a sample chart that you are trying to use and the answer can be tailored for your specific need.